# Получить результат выполнения JavaScript кода в php

Tags: javascript, php

Есть php скрипт который работает в фоне ( nohup php script.php & ).

Так же имеется отдельно JavaScript файл, в котором реализована функция `test(id)`

Мне нужно чтобы через php код вызвать функцию js  test(id) и в php коде получить результат её выполнения в переменную.

Это вообще возможно?)

Либо сохранять js-ом результат выполнения функции в файл а уже с файла читать с помощью php и записывать в php переменную...

Comment: для этого Вам необходим `ajax` запрос на сервер

Comment: В php скрипте?..

Comment: Используете [PHPV8](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js) и вызываете как там указано последней строчкой в примере 
`$v8->executeString('PHP.foo.__call("bar", ["function"]);');`

Comment: Используйте selenuim если ваш javascript расположен на удалённом веб-сервере.

Comment: Javascript на моем сервере

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `ajax` или же `file_get_contents`, чтобы получить результат.

Comment: Как в php скрипте сделать аякс запрос?

Comment: @iKey никак это не сделать

Answer (score 0):

Вообще возможно)
Поставте на сервер nodeJs и в пхп запустите команду

```
echo exec('nodejs /pathToFile/file.js');
```

в самом файле file.js нужно прописать вызов нужной функции

```js
 function test(id){
  //some code
  return id * 5;
 }
test(3); // вызов
```